# Query method not triggered in custom filter handler?

Tags: 7, views

I'm using [Views 3](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

I needed to create a custom *Views filter* that handle dates range. So I looked at example and tried to mimic the behavior and I got some trouble.

It seems that when I extend my own class from `views_handler_filter`, the query method is never invoked, BUT if I extend my class from let's say `views_handler_filter_string` it works.

I must forget something but I'm stuck here.

Here is my code, if someone can take a look and advise me about what happened, I would be very grateful.

Here is my `.views.inc` file :

```
<?php
  class v3d_date_custom_filter extends views_handler_filter {
    var $always_multiple = TRUE;

    function value_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
      //parent::value_form($form, $form_state);
      $form['value']['v3d_date']['period'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Period',
        '#options' => array(
          '7_days' => 'Last 7 days',
          'yesterday' => 'Yesterday',
          'today' => 'Today',
          'custom' => 'Custom dates'),
        '#default_value' => 'custom',
        '#attributes' => array("onclick" => "period_click(this);"),
      );

      $form['value']['v3d_date']['start_date'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
        '#title' => 'Start date',
        '#size' => 30);

      $form['value']['v3d_date']['end_date'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => 'End date',
        '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
        '#size' => 30);
      }

   function exposed_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

     if(is_null($form_state['values']['start_date']) &&
        is_null($form_state['values']['start_date'])) {
        return TRUE;
     }


    /*
     * If we get array for start_date or end_date
     * errors occured, but the date module will handle it.
     */
     if(!is_string($form_state['values']['start_date']) ||
        !is_string($form_state['values']['end_date'])) {
       return TRUE;
     }


     /* Get day, month and year from start_date string */
     if(!preg_match('/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/',
        $form_state['values']['start_date'],
        $start_date
        )) {
       return TRUE; }

     /* Get day, month and year from end_date string */
     if(!preg_match('/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/',
        $form_state['values']['end_date'],
        $end_date
     )) {
       return TRUE; }

     /* Create timestamps and compare */
     $start_date = mktime(0,0,0,$start_date[1],$start_date[2],$start_date[3]);
     $end_date = mktime(0,0,0,$end_date[1],$end_date[2],$end_date[3]);

     if($start_date >= $end_date) {
       form_set_error('start_date','Start date must be anterior to end date.');
     }
   }

   function query() {
     die('fdsfds');
     $this->ensure_my_table();
     $field = "$this->table_alias.$this->real_field";
     dsm($this);
   }

 }
?>
```

And my `.module` file

```
<?php
  function custom_filters_views_api() {
    return array(
      'api'=>3,
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module','custom_filters') . '/views',
    );
  }
?>
```

And  part of my `views_data` that use my custom filter :

```
<?php                                                                                      

function voice_views_data() {

  $data['v_tp_voice']['date_utc_agent'] = array(
    'title' => t('date_utc_agent'),
    'help' => 'date_utc_agent',
    'field' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_field'),
    'filter' => array('handler' => 'v3d_date_custom_filter'),
    'sort' => array('handler' => 'views_handler_sort')
  );

  return $data;
}
```

Comment: To which field your're mapping the custom filter(Field api or custom table).

Comment: it's an sql view(v_tp_voice) taken from an external database called  equalone. so i'm mapping on a custom table.

Comment: Don't know how that could provoke the described effect, but I always thought that the filter class must be in a separate file and being referenced in your .info file too. It's not clear from the question whether that is the case.

Comment: yes you have to extend ! (aka what's your problem ?)

Comment: Why not use the date field module? It has a sub-module integration with views. I am not sure that it will do everything you want, but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [todinov](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/25278/todinov), you can use Drupal contrib modules [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) along with its sub module **Date Views** which will most probably handle any kind of filter in Views. If it doesn't help, you can achieve it through code by implementing [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7).